# Setting an alpha channel when constructing an ImagickPixel

Tags: php, imagemagick, alpha, imagick

I am new to using ImageMagick. I am using the latest imagick extension (3.1.0rc1) with PHP. However, the documentation for imagick seems to be somewhat sparse.

I want to create an [ImagickPixel](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagickpixel.php) object with an alpha channel. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/imagickpixel.setcolor.php) states that these are some valid color values to pass to the constructor: `"blue", "#0000ff", "rgb(0,0,255)", "cmyk(100,100,100,10)", etc`.

I know that it is possible to retrive the alpha value of an ImagickPixel using `getColorValue(imagick::COLOR_ALPHA);`.

So, how can I set an rgb color with an alpha channel during initialization of the object by passing to the constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the way to do it is to just use rgba:

```
$myImagickPixel = new ImagickPixel("rgba(250,15,150,0)"); //Where the last digit is the alpha and 0 is transparent and 1 is fully opaque.
```

Comment: Tried this, but it gives a pink background to the image instead of a transparent background. Also the svg to png conversion, some of the png details are lost.

Answer (score 0):

I found some documentation on the allowed formats:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php

The format you want is "#rrggbbaa", so half-transparent red is "#FF00007F".