# Compatible issues with Imagick Transparent?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, transparent

I have my local with version  ImageMagick 6.7.3-10 (PHP 5.2.10) and server side with  ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 (PHP 5.3.9). It happened that server side doesn't generate transparent background but other colours still working. However local are just good with transparent background. Anyway I can solve in order to use transparent background on server side?

```
$canvas  = new Imagick();
$canvas->newImage( $size, $size, new ImagickPixel( 'transparent' ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried none rather than transparent?

Another answer from Stackoverflow: [Setting an alpha channel when constructing an ImagickPixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103763/setting-an-alpha-channel-when-constructing-an-imagickpixel)

Comment: nice suggestion but I don't think it work still on the server side.. will it ever be happen because of browsing the page too slow and it can't generate the picture properly and turn up black color background?

Answer (score 4):

Well for me didn't work 'none' nor 'transparent' but 'rgba(250,15,150,0)' had ended my long agony with Imagick trully sparse documentation.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you save the result in a format that actually supports transparancy... thus NOT JPG, but GIF or PNG.... It sounds simple, but too often this is forgotten (especially when not explicitly defined)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with code developed locally not working in production for transparent pixels. I tried all the solutions above and transparency simply wasn't working.  In the end I changed `$im->setImageFormat( 'png24' );` to `$im->setImageFormat( 'png' );` and it all started working again.  "png24" format must have been added later.